# Why Getting SIP/2.0 603 Decline TV1 or SIP/2.0 480 Temporarily Unavailable when make outbound call from SIP and destination app is terminated

Tags: sip, pjsip

When I make an Outbound call through VOIP using SIP in ios application I'm
getting this below callback response when the destination app is also using SIP for incoming calls but it is terminated.
**SIP/2.0 100 Telnyx trying

SIP/2.0 180 Ringing

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.1.94:53286;received=122.170.1.34;rport=53286;branch=z9hG4bKPjg48g7A4emKAh3yi2PH7TiweWaKm1s-1h;alias

Record-Route: sip:10.255.0.1;transport=tcp;r2=on;lr;ftag=GcE.YpQwHKrzR-k8XvmfGu3NTVzCZb8W

Record-Route: sip:192.76.120.10;transport=tcp;r2=on;lr;ftag=GcE.YpQwHKrzR-k8XvmfGu3NTVzCZb8W

From: sip:Call123456789@sip.telnyx.com;tag=GcE.YpQwHKrzR-k8XvmfGu3NTVzCZb8W

To: sip:+12294712105@sip.telnyx.com;tag=N5m65F1pZggyN

Call-ID: 4TzmLtUbjGG5Uz-sUi6gdeZYNfko5YGn

CSeq: 4678 INVITE

Contact: sip:+12294712105@10.15.112.4:5070;transport=tcp

Accept: application/sdp

Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REFER, NOTIFY

Supported: path

Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer

Content-Length: 0

--end msg--

18:42:00.954           pjsua_core.c  .RX 589 bytes Response msg 480/INVITE/cseq=4678 (rdata0x108a64338) from TCP 192.76.120.10:5060:
SIP/2.0 480 Temporarily Unavailable

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.1.94:53286;received=122.170.1.34;rport=53286;branch=z9hG4bKPjg48g7A4emKAh3yi2PH7TiweWaKm1s-1h;alias

Max-Forwards: 69

From: sip:Call123456789@sip.telnyx.com;tag=GcE.YpQwHKrzR-k8XvmfGu3NTVzCZb8W

To: sip:+12294712105@sip.telnyx.com;tag=N5m65F1pZggyN

Call-ID: 4TzmLtUbjGG5Uz-sUi6gdeZYNfko5YGn

CSeq: 4678 INVITE

Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REFER, NOTIFY

Supported: path

Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer

Reason: Q.850;cause=16;text="NORMAL_CLEARING"

Content-Length: 0

--end msg--
18:42:00.954           pjsua_core.c  ..TX 374 bytes Request msg ACK/cseq=4678 (tdta0x1091f6aa8) to TCP 192.76.120.10:5060:
ACK sip:+12294712105@sip.telnyx.com SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.1.94:53286;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjg48g7A4emKAh3yi2PH7TiweWaKm1s-1h;alias

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:Call123456789@sip.telnyx.com;tag=GcE.YpQwHKrzR-k8XvmfGu3NTVzCZb8W

To: sip:+12294712105@sip.telnyx.com;tag=N5m65F1pZggyN

Call-ID: 4TzmLtUbjGG5Uz-sUi6gdeZYNfko5YGn

CSeq: 4678 ACK

Content-Length:  0

--end msg--
DISCONNECTED**

Comment: **603 Decline** means the call has been refused. In theory, this is declined by user. But may be you should make your question better to have a cleaner answer. Please edit and add more explanation to your issue.

Comment: @AymericM Ok, thanks

Comment: Sorry, but your question is still uncomplete. Provide details on the product used, provide call flow. Explain if there is user actions... Anything that can help to bring you an answer!

Comment: @AymericM I have attached logs regarding which I am getting disconnected status from the library when I call on the destination number and my destination app is terminated.

Comment: You are receiving a **480 Temporarily Unavailable**, not a **603 Decline**... This means, in theory, that the user you are calling is not registered.